# XSLT grouping based on element attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

My XML file looks like

```
<templates>
    <template type="ORC">
        <field/>
    </template>
    <template type="OBR">
        <field/>
    </template>
    <template type="OBX">
        <field/>
    </template>
    <template type="OBX">
        <field/>
    </template>
    <template type="SPM">
        <field/>
    </template>
    <template type="ORC">
        <field/>
    </template>
    <template type="OBR">
        <field/>
    </template>
    <template type="OBX">
        <field/>
    </template>
    <template type="OBX">
        <field/>
    </template>
    <template type="SPM">
        <field/>
    </template>
</templates>
```

I would like to group the order details (template/@type='ORC') and convert above sample XML into below format with XSLT 2.0

```
<templates>
    <order-details>
        <template type="ORC">
            <field/>
        </template>
        <template type="OBR">
            <field/>
        </template>
        <template type="OBX">
            <field/>
        </template>
        <template type="OBX">
            <field/>
        </template>
        <template type="SPM">
            <field/>
        </template>
    </order-details>
    <order-details>
        <template type="ORC">
            <field/>
        </template>
        <template type="OBR">
            <field/>
        </template>
        <template type="OBX">
            <field/>
        </template>
        <template type="OBX">
            <field/>
        </template>
        <template type="SPM">
            <field/>
        </template>
    </order-details>
</templates>
```

Comment: Grouping would require a common value, you want to split on `@type="ORC"`

Comment: @Tommy - In this case grouping only requires that the group start with `@type="ORC"`. See Pavel's answer to see how to do this in XSLT 2.0. It's also easy in 1.0; I can add an answer with a 1.0 solution if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `group-starting-with` attribute of the [`xsl:for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) to do the grouping the way you want.

Here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="templates">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="template" 
                                group-starting-with="*[@type='ORC']">
                <order-details> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </order-details>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input document produces the expected output as you have specified:

```
<templates>
   <order-details>
      <template type="ORC">
         <field/>
      </template>
      <template type="OBR">
         <field/>
      </template>
      <template type="OBX">
         <field/>
      </template>
      <template type="OBX">
         <field/>
      </template>
      <template type="SPM">
         <field/>
      </template>
   </order-details>
   <order-details>
      <template type="ORC">
         <field/>
      </template>
      <template type="OBR">
         <field/>
      </template>
      <template type="OBX">
         <field/>
      </template>
      <template type="OBX">
         <field/>
      </template>
      <template type="SPM">
         <field/>
      </template>
   </order-details>
</templates>
```